# Host names and URL syntax

Tags: url, ip, uri, hostname

I have done some reading on proper Hostname syntax and can't figure out what is a really proper Hostname/URL syntax
Can you please tell me if the following URLs are syntactically correct?

`1.2.3.4.5.6.7/something

10.123.143.13333/something

1.2.3.4.5.6.7.com/something

some.host.name.com.org/something`

Those are just some examples that i couldn't figure out.
Are those URLs correct?

Answer (score 0):

These are not URLs, as they are missing a [scheme](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.1).

Assuming that you mean HTTP URLs, they would be:

```
http://1.2.3.4.5.6.7/something
http://10.123.143.13333/something
http://1.2.3.4.5.6.7.com/something
http://some.host.name.com.org/something
```

RFC 3986 defines the syntax of the [host subcomponent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) for all URIs (and RFC 2616 for HTTP(S) URIs follows that).

The host names of your example URIs would be:

```
1.2.3.4.5.6.7
10.123.143.13333
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.com
some.host.name.com.org
```

Valid host names follow the syntax defined (in the section linked above) by `IP-literal`, `IPv4address`, or `reg-name`:

1. Check if `IP-literal`:

As an `IP-literal` requires enclosing square brackets (`[`…`]`), none are `IP-literal` host names.

2. Check if `IPv4address`:

As an `IPv4address` must contain exactly three `.` characters, `1.2.3.4.5.6.7`, `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.com`, and `some.host.name.com.org` can’t be `IPv4address` host names.

While `10.123.143.13333` has three `.`, "13333" is not a valid `dec-octet`, so it’s not an `IPv4address`.

3. Check if `reg-name`:

All of your examples are valid `reg-name` host names, as `0-9`, `a-z`, and `.` are allowed characters.

Note that this does *not* mean that these are valid domain names in the DNS. RFC 3986 "does not mandate a particular registered name lookup technology".