# What's the difference between a URL such as "a.b.example" instead of "b.example/a"?

Tags: url, naming, url-design

Why do some websites I see have a URL in the form `a.b.example`, and others are in the form of `b.example/a`?

For example, why is it `gist.github.com` instead of `github.com/gist`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are different *components*. See [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) of the URI standard for a list of components and their definitions.

```
https://gist.github.com/
```

- The *authority* (or more specifically, the *host*) is `gist.github.com`.
- The *path* is `/`.

```
https://github.com/gist
```

- The *authority* (or more specifically, the *host*) is `github.com`.
- The *path* is `/gist`.

As `https://gist.github.com/` would typically also have paths like the second URI (e.g., `https://gist.github.com/foobar`), I guess you are primarily interested in the *authority* component.

In your examples, the [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) gets used, i.e., these are *domains*, which consist of *labels*, [separated by `.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35381296/1591669):

- `gist` is a *third-level domain* ([aka. subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26092914/1591669))
- `github` is a *second-level domain*
- `com` is a *top-level domain* (TLD)

The top level controls the second level, the second level controls the third level, and so on. So if you buy the domain name `github.com`, you typically have control about all of its third-level domains (and fourth-level, etc.).

It’s up to the webmaster which kind of URI design gets used, and the decision can depend on many different factors: what is technically possible for them and the systems they use, usability ([example](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/50372/17023)), SEO ([example](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/50372/17023)), etc. A common reason for using different [host names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30011368/1591669) (domains) is that they can be easily hosted on different servers.

Examples:

- eBay uses different (top-level) domains for each of their localized sites (e.g., `http://www.ebay.de/` for Germany, `http://www.ebay.it/` for Italy)
- Tumblr uses a subdomain for each of their users (e.g., `http://alice.tumblr.com/` for Alice, `http://bob.tumblr.com/` for Bob)
- Twitter uses a path segment for each of their users (e.g., `https://twitter.com/alice` for Alice, `https://twitter.com/bob` for Bob)
- Wikipedia uses subdomains for different languages (e.g., `https://en.wikipedia.org/` for English, `https://fr.wikipedia.org/` for French)