# Difference between third level domain and a path

Tags: url, web, subdomain, url-design

The title sums it up: what’s the difference between something like:

```
support.example.com
```

and

```
example.com/support
```

Is the former simply more permanent and/or easier to dictate?  Or would the destination IP addresses be completely different between the two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a URL such as "a.b.com" instead of "b.com/a"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542139/whats-the-difference-between-a-url-such-as-a-b-com-instead-of-b-com-a)

Comment: @unor thank you!  I didn’t see this posting and it answers my question.  Thanks again